# How to copy a drawing from a Visio page to Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, visio

I am making a tool in Visio to draw electronic designs. When finished, theses designs should then be copied to a word document for further write up and descriptions of designs. I am struggling with the VBA code in Visio to copy the Visio page into the word document. Preferably I would open an existing word template and copy the Visio design after a given Word HEADING or so but for now I have only managed to create a new empty word document but can't find a way to reference the word document.
Could anyone help me with how to paste the selected diagram into the word application please?
This the Visio code I am struggling with:

```
Public Sub CopyVsoPgToWord()
   Dim objWord
   Dim objDoc
   Dim vsoPage As Visio.Page
   Dim DocName As String
   
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   objWord.Visible = True
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

   ActiveWindow.SelectAll
   Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy
   With objDoc
      .Paste  'this doesnt work
      'past the Visio diagram into word page 2
   End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The [Paste](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.paste) method appear on a number of classes like `Range`, so you just need to find one of those.  The [Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.content) property of `Document` will give you a `Range` but you could change that depending on where you want to insert the object.

You might also find it easier to add a reference to the Word object model (via Tools / References / Microsoft Word).

Anyway, have a go with this:

```
   Dim wdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
   
   Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   wdApp.Visible = True
   Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Templates\1033\OriginReport.Dotx")

   Dim vApp As Visio.Application
   Dim vSel As Visio.Selection
   
   Set vApp = Visio.Application
   
   Set vSel = vApp.ActivePage.CreateSelection(visSelTypeAll, Visio.VisSelectMode.visSelModeSkipSuper)
   vSel.Copy
   
   wdDoc.Content.Paste
```

(Your getting a Selection from the window will also work here)

Comment: John, thanks for the reply to my question. I sorry but I am getting a compile error on the Me.Application statement. What do I need to doe to resolve that?

Comment: That's the note about being in ThisDocument.  If you're just in a normal module then you can do away with the "Me." and, in fact, you can do away with it anyway as for Visio it is the default Global property.  I think any time you're dealing with multiple object models (Visio and Word in this case) it's worth trying to be explicit so probably this line might be nicer: `Set vApp = Visio.Application`